# Android three circles different sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I have 3 circles in android that show progress, are a custom element (ViewProgressbar) that inherit from relative layout.

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="center">

  <com.theproject.ui.view.ViewProgressbar
  android:id="@+id/vps_history_progress1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:value= "@string/zero"
  app:subject = "@string/txt_progress1"
  />

  <com.theproject.ui.view.ViewProgressbar
    android:id="@+id/vps_history_progress2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:value= "@string/zero"
    app:subject = "@string/txt_progress2" 
  />

  <com.theproject.ui.view.ViewProgressbar
      android:id="@+id/vps_history_progress3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:value= "@string/zero"
      app:subject = "@string/txt_progress3"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I am facing is that in devices with small screen the thrid circle is smaller than the others. I think is related that I am using wrap_content. Is there a way to force the three circles have the same size?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Use the `weight` attribute:

```
 <com.theproject.ui.view.ViewProgressbar
   android:id="@+id/vps_history_progress1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight=1
   app:value= "@string/zero"
   app:subject = "@string/txt_progress1"
 />
```

Repeat this for your other views inside your LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your Resource with this.
Notice the WeightSum is 3 and each child is a 1 to add up to 3.
Each child will be evenly spaced Horizontally.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3"
android:gravity="center">

<com.theproject.ui.view.ViewProgressbar
android:id="@+id/vps_history_progress1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
app:value= "@string/zero"
app:subject = "@string/txt_progress1"
/>

<com.theproject.ui.view.ViewProgressbar
android:id="@+id/vps_history_progress2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
app:value= "@string/zero"
app:subject = "@string/txt_progress2" 
/>

<com.theproject.ui.view.ViewProgressbar
android:id="@+id/vps_history_progress3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
app:value= "@string/zero"
app:subject = "@string/txt_progress3"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```